# Append xml tree to another xml tree in PHP using DOMDocuments

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am looking to append an xml tree to another.

For example, I want the following xml:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
  </b>
</a>
```

To have the following xml inside it:

```
<n:d xmlns:xsl="namespace">
  <n:e>
    <n:f/>
  </n:e>
</n:d>
```

so that it looks like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
    <n:d xmlns:n="namespace">
      <n:e>
        <n:f/>
      </n:e>
    </n:d>
  </b>
</a>
```

The code that I have attempting and failing to do this is as follows:

```
$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2 = new DOMDocument();

$doc1->loadXML($xml1);
$doc2->loadXML($xml2);

$node_To_Insert = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('d')->item(0);
$node_To_Be_Inserted_To = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('b')->item(0);

$node_To_Be_Inserted_To->appendChild($doc1->importNode($node_To_Insert));

echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($doc1->saveXML(),true)).'</pre>';
```

The current result I get from the echo:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
    <n:d xmlns:n="namespace" />
  </b>
</a>
```

I am out of ideas that aren't impossible to read, or aren't seemingly stupidly roundabout.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is very close. You only need to perform a [deep copy with importNode](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) to get the result you want.

```
$node_To_Be_Inserted_To->appendChild($doc1->importNode($node_To_Insert, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the native way to handle XML transformations such as [merging documents](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) is using XSLT, the special-purpose language designed primarily for this need to re-structure, re-style, re-format XML documents for various end-use needs.

Much like another special-purpose language, SQL, is for databases, XSLT is handy with XML files. And PHP comes equipped with an XSLT processor (might need to enable the extension: `php_xsl.so`) .

**XSLT**  *(save as .xsl or .xslt file)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
    <b>
      <xsl:copy-of select="c" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('doc2.xml')"/>
    </b>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** *(load only first doc as XSLT above loads second doc at specific node)*

```
$doc1 = new DOMDocument();    
$doc1->load('doc1.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Transform XML source
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc1);

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = 'Output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXml);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
    <n:d xmlns:n="namespace">
      <n:e>
        <n:f/>
      </n:e>
    </n:d>
  </b>
</a>
```